# How to remove filter frame in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When I create a filter `setBasicFilter` using api or add it by hand it adds a green frame around the range:

[image]

Is it possible to remove it with Google Sheets API v4 or manually? Or change the color of it to gray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I am sorry of not being able to provide you the answer you want to hear, but unfortunately it is not possible.

See this [Google Support Post](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/2234563?hl=en):

> ​You can't get rid of it as it is used as a "visual aid" to let you
> see you have a filter set. ​
>
> If you would like to influence future
> feature additions like this, I highly recommend leaving feedback by
> following these steps:
>
> 1. Open the file where you've noticed the bug or technical issue.
> 2. Click the Help menu.
> 3. Click Report a problem.
> 4. Complete > the questionnaire.
>
> The more people who have this suggestion, the
> more likely the team will make a change.The product team reviews this
> feedback regularly and uses it to better improve the product over
> time.